# Как центровать контент c background-image на все окно браузера

Tags: css

Имеется сайт, например: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отцентрировать всю контентную часть сайта единым стилем?

Если всю контентную часть обернуть в div например с классом content и задать ширину 980px, то нельзя задать изображение на всю ширину окна как в хедере (в скриншоте), тогда приходится вводить дополнительные обертки, например в хедер. Сначала задать самому блоку хедер картинку на 100%, а потом уже всех детей оборачивать в обертку.

Получается единой оберткой не отцентровать все блоки? Только в каждый блок вводить дополнительную обертку, правильно понимаю?

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если вам нужно обернуть один блок в несколько доп. `div` это не критично и не стоит на этом зацикливаться.

Comment: Приложите конкретный код с серией картинок. И будет вам решение.

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой вариант:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff url('https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2017/08/07/12/1502137604118189937.jpg') no-repeat center top / auto 100vh;
}
```

Разберём:
`#fff` - цвет фона, в данном случае всё пространство за картинкой. | [background-color](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-color)
`url('...')` - ссылка на картинку. | [background-image](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-image)
`no-repeat` - отключение повтора картинки | [background-repeat](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-repeat)
`center top` - положение картинки (горизонтально по центру, сверху по вертикали) | [background-position](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position)
`auto 100vh` - размер картинки (ширина пропорционально от реальных размеров, высота равна высоте экрана) | [background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size)

---

Конкретно вашего случая, я обычно делаю так:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2017/08/07/12/1502137604118189937.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
}

.max-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="max-wrap"></div>
</div>

<div class="max-wrap">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultricies aliquam dui vel tempor. Morbi molestie elit vitae lectus commodo consectetur. Phasellus a justo tincidunt, interdum purus ac, pellentesque sem. Phasellus iaculis purus eget dictum elementum. Nunc cursus eros sed est ullamcorper, eu consectetur lacus ultrices. Nullam nec hendrerit arcu. Fusce non quam purus. Integer non vulputate odio, vitae convallis purus. Praesent dictum lobortis ante, vel placerat tellus aliquet et. Cras commodo ipsum vitae purus congue, vitae placerat tortor commodo. Praesent ut sapien nunc. Donec mollis, urna a sodales rhoncus, ante turpis vulputate ex, et porttitor velit odio eget magna. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
image{
background-image:url();
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Попробуй, может получится.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте :before/:after и установите с помощье его задний фон с `position: absolute;`...

Либо задайте `header` и родителю с контентом одинаковый класс, в котором укажите стили...